# Creating an if statement with different variables from a database?

Tags: php

First time poster and inexperienced coder here. The job I have requires me to do all kinds of random tasks with maintaining the website, most of them being related to HTML and very basic PHP.  However, today I was asked to do something a little beyond my own knowledge.  We have a letter we send out to members that is generated using a mixture of HTML and PHP, the data being drawn from our database.  My task is to add in a message informing different member types of dues increasing.  In the DB, these are listed as `id_customer_type` (`1`, `2`, `3`, etc). I am pretty lost on how exactly to do this.  Would I use `if` statements?  `Elseif`?

An example of my awful coding might give you a general idea of what I'm going for:

```
Annual dues will increase to <?php if('id_customer_type'='1,4') echo "$295" ?> on January 1, 2014
```

I have 3 separate messages that need to be coded, each one using 2 customer types.

Sorry if this isn't how questions are supposed to be done, I'm fairly new here.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: This seems a little more like a logic issue rather than a programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant method I'd use for something like would be a php switch statement. Some languages only allow you to use a switch only for numeric data types but in PHP you can evaluate almost anything and it's easier to read and see where you need to make changes instead of confusing nested if-else statements.

If you assigned the customer type to a variable $id_customer_type an example might be:

```
Annual dues will increase to <?php 

switch($id_customer_type)
{
  case 1:
  case 4:
    echo "$295";
    break;

  case 2:
    echo "$195";
    break;

  case 3:
    echo "$395";
    break; 

  default:
    echo "$0";    
?> on January 1, 2014
```

In this example above customers of type 1 and 4 will get an $295 increase because there is no break statement after case 1. Customers of type 2 get and increase of type $195 etc.

Remember to always use break statements to exit the switch otherwise you'll see things like customers getting increases of things like '$295$195'.

Using a default is also good practise to handle cases where you don't have a case to handle a certain customer type.

Good luck!